# How to mock partial fields in Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring-boot, mockito, junit4

I am writing unit tests for My service layer. My service layer have multiple fields that are autowired. I want to Mock only one of them and others to initialize as autowired.

Service Interface

```
public interface ProductSupplierService {

    Map<String, List<? extends BaseDTO>> getProductSuppliers(Long productId, Long tenantId);

    ProductSupplierDTO addProductSupplier(Long productId, Long tenantId, ProductSupplierDTO productSupplierDTO);

    ProductSupplierDTO editProductSupplier(Long productId, Long supplierId, Long tenantId,
            ProductSupplierDTO productSupplierDTO);

    void deleteProductSupplier(Long productId, Long supplierId, Long tenantId);
}
```

Service Implementation

```
@Service
public class ProductSupplierServiceImpl implements ProductSupplierService {

    private MapperFacade mapper;

    @Autowired
    public void setMapperFactory(MapperFactory mapperFactory) {
        this.mapper = mapperFactory.getMapperFacade();
    }

    @Autowired
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    private ProductManager productManager;

    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ProductSupplierServiceImpl.class);

    @Override
    public Map < String, List << ? extends BaseDTO >> getProductSuppliers(Long productId, Long tenantId) {
        Product product = fetchProductByProductIdAndTenantId(productId, tenantId);
        ListResponse listResponse = new ListResponse();
        if (CollectionUtil.nonNullNonEmpty(product.getProductSuppliers())) {
            List < ProductSupplierDTO > productSupplierDTOS = new ArrayList < > (0);
            product.getProductSuppliers().stream().filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .forEach(productSupplier - > productSupplierDTOS
                    .add(productSupplier.toDTO(ProductSupplierDTO.class, mapper)));
            listResponse.addResponse("product_suppliers", productSupplierDTOS);
        }
        return listResponse.getResponse();
    }

    @Override
    public ProductSupplierDTO addProductSupplier(Long productId, Long tenantId, ProductSupplierDTO productSupplierDTO) {
        Product product = fetchProductByProductIdAndTenantId(productId, tenantId);
        ProductSupplier productSupplier = productSupplierDTO.toModel(ProductSupplier.class, mapper);
        if (product.getProductSuppliers().add(productSupplier)) {
            productManager.applyProductSupplier(product, tenantId, productSupplier);
            product.setModified(new Date());
            try {
                productRepository.save(product);
                Optional < ProductSupplier > savedProductSupplier = product.getProductSuppliers().stream()
                    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                    .filter(ps - > ps.getSupplierId().equals(productSupplierDTO.getSupplierId())).findFirst();
                if (savedProductSupplier.isPresent()) {
                    return savedProductSupplier.get().toDTO(ProductSupplierDTO.class, mapper);
                } else {
                    throw new UnexpectedException();
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                throw new UnexpectedException();
            }
        } else {
            throw new BusinessValidationException("supplier already exists");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public ProductSupplierDTO editProductSupplier(Long productId, Long supplierId, Long tenantId,
        ProductSupplierDTO productSupplierDTO) {
        Product product = fetchProductByProductIdAndTenantId(productId, tenantId);
        Optional < ProductSupplier > productSupplierOptional = product.getProductSuppliers().stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(productSupplier - > productSupplier.getSupplierId().equals(supplierId)).findFirst();
        if (productSupplierOptional.isPresent()) {
            ProductSupplier productSupplier = productSupplierOptional.get();
            if (Objects.nonNull(productSupplierDTO.getBuyPrice())) {
                productSupplier.setBuyPrice(productSupplierDTO.getBuyPrice());
            }
            if (Objects.nonNull(productSupplierDTO.isDefaultSupplier())) {
                if (productSupplierDTO.isDefaultSupplier()) {
                    product.getProductSuppliers().forEach(supplier - > supplier.setDefaultSupplier(false));
                    productSupplier.setDefaultSupplier(true);
                } else {
                    productSupplier.setDefaultSupplier(false);
                }
            }
            productSupplier.setModified(new Date());

            product.setModified(new Date());
            try {
                productRepository.save(product);
                return productSupplier.toDTO(ProductSupplierDTO.class, mapper);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                throw new UnexpectedException();
            }
        } else {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(ProductSupplier.class, String.valueOf(supplierId));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteProductSupplier(Long productId, Long supplierId, Long tenantId) {
        Product product = fetchProductByProductIdAndTenantId(productId, tenantId);
        Optional < ProductSupplier > productSupplierOptional = product.getProductSuppliers().stream()
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .filter(productSupplier - > productSupplier.getSupplierId().equals(supplierId)).findFirst();
        if (productSupplierOptional.isPresent()) {
            product.getProductSuppliers().remove(productSupplierOptional.get());
            product.setModified(new Date());
            try {
                productRepository.save(product);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                throw new UnexpectedException();
            }
        } else {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(ProductSupplier.class, String.valueOf(supplierId));
        }
    }

    private Product fetchProductByProductIdAndTenantId(Long productId, Long tenantId) {
        Product product = productRepository.findByIdAndTenantId(productId, tenantId);
        if (Objects.nonNull(product)) {
            return product;
        } else {
            throw new EntityNotFoundException(Product.class, String.valueOf(productId));
        }
    }
}
```

Test class

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class ProductSupplierServiceUnitTest {

    @Mock
    private ProductRepository productRepository;

    @Autowired
    @InjectMocks
    private ProductSupplierServiceImpl productSupplierService;

    @Test(expected = EntityNotFoundException.class)
    public void productNotFound() {
        Mockito.when(productRepository.findByIdAndTenantId(invalidProductId, tenantId)).thenReturn(null);
        productSupplierService.getProductSuppliers(invalidProductId, tenantId);
    }

    @Test
    public void getProductSuppliersSuccess() {

        initProduct();
        initProductSupplier();

        Set < ProductSupplier > productSuppliers = new HashSet < > (Collections.singletonList(productSupplierBuilder.get()));
        Product product = productBuilder.setProductSuppliers(productSuppliers).get();
        product.setId(validProductId);

        Mockito.when(productRepository.findByIdAndTenantId(validProductId, tenantId)).thenReturn(product);

        Map < String, List << ? extends BaseDTO >> result = productSupplierService.getProductSuppliers(validProductId,
            tenantId);
        Assert.assertEquals(result.size(), 1);
        Assert.assertTrue(result.containsKey("product_suppliers"));
    }

    @Test
    public void getProductSuppliersEmpty() {

        initProduct();
        initProductSupplier();

        Product product = productBuilder.setProductSuppliers(Collections.emptySet()).get();
        product.setId(validProductId);

        Mockito.when(productRepository.findByIdAndTenantId(validProductId, tenantId)).thenReturn(product);

        Map < String, List << ? extends BaseDTO >> result = productSupplierService.getProductSuppliers(validProductId,
            tenantId);

        Assert.assertTrue(result.isEmpty());
    }

}
```

I want only productRepository field to be mocked but productManager & mapper fields must be initialized automatically.

Problem is productManager & mapper fields are null when running tests.

Is it possible to initialize them automatically? Like they are initialized when running spring boot application with fully loaded context.

Comment: You don't want to have autowired fields in your unit tests; mock them and make sure their methods are called properly. If you need their results, mock those as well.

Comment: I want actual method calls for class ProductManager & it also have some autowired fields and if I spy that field then autowire chain will be stopped

Comment: Just make it a regular Spring Boot test, create a field of type `ProductRepository` in your test class and mark with `@MockBean`. See https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-mocking-beans

Comment: Thanks but I have already tried it & it works as expected but problem is that it load full spring boot application & as I am writing unit tests, I want to load only required context.

Comment: Is it possible to provide custom context for test that scans packages for Component & Service annotation and autowire them?

Answer (score 0):

If "productManager" & "mapper" are simple classes just add:

```
@Spy
ProductManager productManager = new ProductManager();

@Spy
Mapper mapper = new Mapper();
```

Mockito knows to objects annotated with @Spy for @InjectMocks. If those classes have @Autowired fields of their own it is beyond capabilities of Mockito and common solution is to use SpringJUnit4ClassRunner and use Mockito in Spring context config:

```
<bean id="mockBean" class="org.mockito.Mockito" factory-method="mock">
    <constructor-arg value="some.real.bean.Class" />
</bean>
```

Comment: No, they aren't simple classes. ProductManager also have some autowired fields.

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the last comment from @Harshit yes, you can configure a context just for your test:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest(classes = {ExampleTestConfiguration.class})
```

... define your included and excluded packages in the @ComponentScan in ExampleTestConfiguration